# No module named 'allauth.account.context_processors'

Tags: python, django, package, django-allauth, django-settings

I want to use Django-Allauth, so I installed as following and it works perfectly in my laptop localhost; but when I pull it in my server, I 
encounter with the following error:

```
No module named 'allauth.account.context_processors'
```

What should I do?

```
# Django AllAuth
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # Already defined Django-related contexts here

                # `allauth` needs this from django
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.core.context_processors.request',

                # `allauth` specific context processors
                'allauth.account.context_processors.account',
                'allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount',
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.core.context_processors.debug",
                "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
                "django.core.context_processors.media",
                "django.core.context_processors.static",
                "django.core.context_processors.tz",
                "django.core.context_processors.request",
                "moolak.context_processors.image",
            ],
        },
    },
]


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
    {'google':
        {'SCOPE': ['profile', 'email'],
         'AUTH_PARAMS': {'access_type': 'online'}}}


SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
    {'facebook': {'SCOPE': ['email', 'public_profile', 'user_friends'], 'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'}, 'METHOD': 'js_sdk', 'VERSION': 'v2.3'}}


# newsletter

NEWSLETTER_DEFAULT_HEADER_SENDER = 'NewsLetter <info@m.com>'
```

I never used Django-Alluth, so I am newbie, please help me as easy as you can.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: No! it is not solved!

Comment: have you run the command pip --freeze?In that what is the version of allauth ?

Comment: In our project also we faced this problem, but when we shifted to previous version of all auth the problem was solved

Comment: django-allauth==0.22.0

Comment: @gaurav_kamble How can I do this?

Comment: As @Andre has mentioned you have to do pip install django-allauth==0.21.0 for the previous version

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This means you have different versions of Allauth in your dev machine and in your server. You should definitely use the same version on both sides.

Into the why of the issue you are hitting on the server, in version 0.22 of django-allauth, the [context processors have been replaced by template tags](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/release-notes.html#id17).

You just need to ensure that:

1. You are running at least Allauth 0.22, which is the latest version as of now (`pip install django-allauth==0.22`)
2. No Allauth-specific context processors are listed in your Django project settings. So you need to remove these two lines:

```
# `allauth` specific context processors
'allauth.account.context_processors.account',
'allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount',
```

Comment: This should definetely be the answer, it solved my issue

Comment: The fix is applicable for `No module named context_processors` too if allauth is in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: I had Django 1.8.2 + django-allauth 0.20.0 and it was working fine with the 2 lines. But when upgrading to Django 1.9.3 + django-allauth 0.24.1, I had the "ImportError at /admin/ No module named 'allauth.account.context_processors'" error.
Removing these 2 lines fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

This error means that the module could not be found.

You probably just need to install the 3rd party module called `allauth` on your server (or add it to requirements.txt, if you are using automatic deploys like on Heroku).

```
pip install django-allauth
```

You can run `pip freeze` locally to see which modules are installed.

To install a specific version of `django-allauth`, use:

```
pip install django-allauth==0.22.0
```

Comment: I installed allauth via pip!

Comment: django-allauth==0.22.0

Comment: And this is the version that you installed on the server as well? Did you install it in a virtualenv or globally? Maybe the server uses a different environment than you think, this could happen if it's running in a virtualenv, on a different Python version (e.g. 2 instead of 3) or if your [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) is broken.

Comment: I installed it via virtualenv, python 3.4

Comment: Ok, cool. Are you sure that your server is using the same environment?

Comment: How can I be sure? But I think so!

Comment: What kind of server is this? How is the Django application served (see [How to deploy with WSGI](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/))

Comment: I am using Digitalocean, and the site worked perfectly before allauth.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84347/discussion-between-andre-laszlo-and-altruistic).

Answer (score 1):

It had problem with allauth 0.22.0, install allauth 0.20.0

```
pip install django-allauth==0.20.0
```

Comment: I find it a bit funny that you added this answer yourself, since it was already in my answer, as well as in the comments :) Julen's answer is very good too, since it adds some background.

Answer (score 0):

You can run pip freeze locally to see which modules are installed.

To install a specific version of django-allauth, use. It will solve the issue.

pip install django-allauth==0.22.0