# django-allauth: import error

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I continuously seem to get the following import error:

[image]

In my settings.py, I have all the comma's in the correct places in templates:

[image]

and I have installed django-allauth .22 in both of my Virtual environments I am using, yet I still recieve this error. Even thought `allauth.account.context_processors.account` is commented out, I recieve the same error when I uncomment that. This is from [this](http://www.marinamele.com/user-authentication-with-google-using-django-allauth) tutorial. I have seen questions about this but they were all fixed by simply adding a comma or installing django-allauth to the virtualenv. Any ideas?

Comment: You did notice, that you only commented one of the allauth context processors (there is another one right below the commented one)? Both are raising the error. [Current documentation](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html) for django-allauth makes no mention of the need for those context processors and they don't exist any more in [the source code](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/tree/master/allauth/socialaccount)

Comment: Yes I only showed one raising the error, but the other does too. I'm new to django and the tutorial told me to use them. Maybe the tutorial is old

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. **Post the actual text**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No module named 'allauth.account.context\_processors'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31648019/no-module-named-allauth-account-context-processors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

django-allauth no longer makes use of context processors since version [0.21.0](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/changelog.html):

> Template context processors are no longer used. The context processor for allauth.account was already empty, and the context processor for allauth.socialaccount has been converted into the `{% get_providers %}` template tag.

You should be able to simply remove the references to *both* context processors without problems.