# PyCharm console - no module named

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I've recently renamed project and its apps. When I run development server through Windows command line it works correctly. The problem is that when I run server through PyCharm (I've set virtualenv), it says (I've recently installed `django-allauth`):

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x03767B30>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Milano\Desktop\Projekty\venvs\sflvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Milano\Desktop\Projekty\venvs\sflvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 107, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Milano\Desktop\Projekty\venvs\sflvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 252, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "C:\Users\Milano\Desktop\Projekty\venvs\sflvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Milano\Desktop\Projekty\venvs\sflvenv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Milano\Desktop\Projekty\venvs\sflvenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Milano\Desktop\Projekty\venvs\sflvenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 86, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named allauth
```

What I've done:

1. Replaced all apps with new names, project too.
2. Removed .idea folder to make PyCharm create fresh new.
3. Set virtualenv

What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

Install the package while your `virtualenv` is activated:

```
pip install django-allauth
```

If you're sure you have it installed, try this:

No Allauth-specific context processors are listed in your Django project settings. So you need to remove these two lines:

```
# `allauth` specific context processors
'allauth.account.context_processors.account',
'allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount',
```

---

A relevant [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31648019/no-module-named-allauth-account-context-processors)